# Enable different ROS log levels

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Configuration) about how to set `environment variables` to change log level and my `config` file stayed like this:

```
 log4j.logger.ros=DEBUG
 log4j.logger.ros.hector_path_follower=DEBUG
```

`ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE` variable is properly set, however `rosconsole` output doesn't show any message.

So I've got two questions:

1- What possible might be wrong?
2- How can I enable `ROS_DEBUG` output to be viewed on a file/screen, not only through rosconsole

EDIT:

Running roslaunch file outputs:

`log4cxx: Could not read configuration file [/home/bruno/rodain].`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284466/enable-different-ros-log-levels/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. the error points to a wrong file location. You have to specify the full path to the file, including the file name and file extension. So if your file is not named `/home/bruno/rodain`, you need to adapt it to the full file name (e.g. `/home/bruno/custom_roslog.conf`).
2. By changing the logger level and putting the  `output="screen"` [argument](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) in the respective `node` tags of your launch file. E.g. `<node name="my_node" pkg="my_pkg" type="my_node_executable" output="screen"/>`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2018-03-12**:
@mig Your solution resolved my issue. However, `ros_console` is not displaying any log messages anymore. I've set my config_file to behave like default, not changed though.